# Compare two Jsons

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

For example, I have two Jsons: the first one I gave from Test Constructor, the second I gave such a user result of a test (I'm using the JS libriry - survey.js) :

The First :

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page 1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "checkbox",
     "name": "question 1",
     "correctAnswer": [
      "item1",
      "item3"
     ],
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    },
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "question 2",
     "correctAnswer": "item2",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

The Second:

```
{
"question 1":["item3","item1"],
"question 2":"item2"
}
```

How should I compare those two Jsons by correctAnswer?

I require result such: 
question 1 - wrong,
question 2 - right.

Comment: Deserialize them, find the question, compare the answer to the correct ones.

Comment: @John I understand that but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @AlexeySamovich have a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json for example to serialize/deserialize stuff also http://json2csharp.com/ to create the right classes for a given json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as user gsharp mentioned you can use json.NET to achieve this.
Just do the following: create your classes that will hold the survey form:

```
public class SurveyForm
{
    [JsonProperty("pages")]
    public IEnumerable<SurveyPage> Pages { get; set; } 
}

public class SurveyPage
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("elements")]
    public IEnumerable<SurveyPageElement> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class SurveyPageElement
{
    // I think you can do the rest
}

public class SurveyResult
{
    // same as the other classes
}
```

Do you notice the `JsonProperty` Attribute? Use that to tell json.NET where to find the related properties in your json. You actually don't need to do that because json.NET does some magic to find the correct properties by it's own but I think it is useful to do it by my own.

Then deserialize the two Jsons:

```
var surveyForm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SurveyForm>(surveyFormJson);
var surveyResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>>>(surveyResultJson);
```

EDIT: To compare the both do something like this:

```
foreach(var page in surveyForm.Pages)
{
    foreach(var element in page.Elements)
    {
        if(element.CorrectAnswers.All(surveyResult[element.Name].Contains))
        {
            // right
        }
        else
        {
            // wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks and how to compare those two Jsons according to example?